# Dynamic form submission (Ajax?)

Tags: controllers, forms, ajax

I try to implement a quotation form. 
I then created a new module with a phtml file containing the form (with several input / input-select) and the price calculation result.

Now I would like the form to be "dynamic", i.e. that the price is updated each time a parameter (input) is changed and not to have to click on a button to submit manually the form.

I have been told that to avoid a full reload of the page each time a value is changed I had to use Ajax request? Could you confirm please?

How may I implement that?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: I managed to do it. Here is the solution if it can help :

First the .phtml form:

```
<form id="form-configurator" class="form-configurator " name="formconfigurator" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="item" id="item-1">
        <label class="conf_label">BlaBla</label>
        <div class="inputselect">
            <select class="selector" name="name1" id="input-1"><option value="2" selected="selected">2</option><option value="4">4</option></select>    
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item" id="item-2">
        <label class="conf_label">Quantity :</label>
        <div class="inputselect">
            <input id="input-quantity" name="quantity" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="50" style="width: 63px;" maxlength="2" class="input-text required-entry"></input>
        </div>
    </div>

    <strong><span class="devis_Nb" id="Devis_totalF"></span></strong>
</form>
```

Th JS/ajax script (which send data to php controller and treat the answer):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
(function($) {

  function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'mymodule/index/mymethode' ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data : $("#form-configurator").serializeArray(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);    
            $("#Devis_totalF").html(data['total_price']);

        },
        error: function ()
        {
        }
    });
  }

// for number type input scan
$('input[type=number]').change(function() {
       doAjax();
    }
  });

// for selectinput scan
$("select").change(function() {
    doAjax();
  });

  //To run script at page load
  doAjax();

})(jQuery);
//]]>
</script>
```

and the controller.php file:

```
<?php
class Mine_mymodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
   }

   public function mymethodeAction()
   {
    //if ($post = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

    $output = array();

    $output = array('total_price' => 10);

    echo json_encode($output);

    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onchange` events on each field.
If your price needs to be calculated serverside, an ajax request is needed to one of your custom controllers.
But it would be better if you can implement your logic in javascript also because this way you avoid unnecessary calls to the server.
Using the same event you can see if all the fields are filled in, and then submit the form.
But for a better user experience I recommend that you let the customer click a button when he is done. This way you avoid (or at least reduce) the requests with wrong data filled in.
Let the customer decide when he is done.